Docker bind not working for external disk
I'm curently setup a jellyfin in my local infrastructure, on a ubuntu 24.04 server.
Here is my docker compose file :
services:
  jellyfin:
    image: jellyfin/jellyfin:2024102105-amd64
    container_name: jellyfin
    network_mode: 'host'
    volumes:
      - config:/config
      - cache:/cache
      - type: bind
        source: /disk/toshiba1/jellyfin
        target: /media
    restart: 'always'
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'

volumes:
  config:
  cache:

When I start my container, the /disk/toshiba1/jellyfin folder
is not mounted inside the /media folder, so data inside /disk/toshiba1/jellyfin are not in the /media folder of the container. The container start normaly, but there is nothing inside /media (there is data on my /disk/toshiba1/jellyfin folder)
Additional information :

/disk/toshiba1 is a external disk mounted, type ext4 (rw,relatime)
I try to mount the media folder with one of my home folder and it works
I try to put my jellyfin folder on 777, but no changes
Same with running the container in privilege mode and apparmor unconfined

Here is the volume inspection of the jellyfin container during his life
{
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/disk/toshiba1/jellyfin",
    "Destination": "/media",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
}

Thanks in advance !
